Why for this sentence "このカメラは、プロの写真家 ( ) 、普通の人間には使いこなせないだろう",　ならまだしも? is better thanに比べて？
this sentence is extracted from N1 test in July 2021,
このカメラは、プロの写真家 ( _____ ) 、普通の人間には使いこなせないだろう.
I am wondering why the correct answer is  ならまだしも,  instead of に比べて ?

You probably already understand how まだしも works, so let's focus on why the following sentence is less natural:

このカメラは、プロの写真家に比べて、普通の人間には使いこなせないだろう。

This sentence may not be entirely incorrect, but it does sound unnatural to me.
First, 使いこなせない is not really a "comparable" trait. Also in English, it's usually unnatural to say "more impossible" or "most impossible". If relative comparison were intended, 使いこなしにくい or 使いこなすのが難しい would be far better.
Second, even if we overlook this issue and read the sentence as something expressing relative comparison, "Regarding this camera, when compared to professional photographers, ordinary people are worse at using it" would not be natural as a description of a specific camera. It's obvious that professionals are generally better at using cameras, so it's hard to imagine when a sentence like this is needed. Of course this is a matter of semantics rather than grammar, but it's important.
After swapping the two, a sentence like the following would look like a natural description of some unique camera, both in terms of grammar and semantics:

このカメラは、普通の人間に比べて、プロの写真家の方が使いこなすのが難しいだろう。

